# Docker client does not run on Windows for now. Please use ssh to SSH into the VM instead

Tags: docker, boot2docker

```
PS C:\Users\me> boot2docker start
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
...........ooooo
Started.

Writing C:\Users\me\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\ca.pem C:\Users\me\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\cert.pem C:\Users\me\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\key.pem

**Docker client does not run on Windows for now. Please use
    "C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows\boot2docker.exe" ssh
to SSH into the VM instead.**
```

How to resole this error?

Comment: Have you tried doing "C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows\boot2docker.exe" ssh to SSH into the VM instead."?

Comment: Can u mentions the steps for doing C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows\boot2docker.exe" ssh to SSH into the VM instead."?

Answer (score 0):

See [b2d.bat](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/master/b2d.bat) as an example of a script launching a boot2docker session:

```
@echo off
boot2docker start
boot2docker ssh
```

(with `boot2docker.exe` being in your `%PATH%`, like `C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows`)

You need both steps:

- the `boot2docker start` starts the VirtualBox Tiny Core VM (if it was already started, it does nothing)
- the `boot2docker ssh` opens an interactive ssh session to that VM.

Comment: Thanks for giving replay,  i want to create new b2d.bat file or edit exiting file

Comment: @kesava I agree. Do you have any issue in writing that `b2d.bat` script (with the 3 lines which are in my answer)?

Comment: where i have to write "b2d.bat"  script, (this location C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows )

Comment: @kesava wherever you want. All you need for that script to work is to make sure "`C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows`" is in `%PATH%`.

Comment: i removied my boot2docker 1.5 and i installed 1.6 now it's working fine,

Answer (score 0):

Docker CLI 1.6 is available for Windows.
https://blog.docker.com/2015/04/docker-release-1-6/

Answer (score 0):

Incase you still dont know how to fix it: just install the latest v1.6 version and it will support windows cmd.exe